# nth-child selector, something weird

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Fiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/a45ha/

HTML here -

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="a">Class A</div>
    <div class="b">Class B1</div>
    <div class="b">Class B2</div>
    <div class="b">Class B3</div>
    <div class="b">Class B4</div>
    <div class="b">Class B5</div>
</div>​
```

Jquery here -

```
$(function(){
    $(".parent").children(".b:nth-child(2)").css("color", "red");
});​
```

Above I have written `.b:nth-child(2)` so why I am not able to select second element of `class="b"` ?

I want to highlight **Class B2** as `color:red`, but I am getting **Class B1** as `color:red`. What is the problem guys ? If that is how it is works then according to me it is a bug in this type of selector.

The fiddle is just to let you know guys what is my problem but in my real problem I have having `nth-child(2)` as `nth-child(j + 1)` where `j` plays other role as well and it cannot make it `j+2`.

Can anyone please let me know the workaround to highlight **class B2**

Comment: The jQuery `nth-child` is derived from the CSS specification. As such it is 1-indexed, not 0-indexed.

Comment: ok so why I am not able to select second child of class="b" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you use `:eq(2)` instead of `:nth-child(2)`. 
In order to get B2 you would write:

```
$(".parent").children(".b:eq(1)").css("color", "red");
```

**Update**

For your original question why `:nth-child(2)` is not selecting the second child, I found the reason. On [jQuery docs site](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) i found:

> The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with :eq(n), even
>   though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements.
>   **With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they
>   are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the
>   selector attached to the pseudo-class.** With :eq(n) only the selector
>   attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of
>   any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.

So in your case

`$(".parent").children(".b:nth-child(2)").css("color", "red");`

the `:nth-child(2)` counts the children of `.parent` and returns only if the element is `.b`

Answer (score 0):

[`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) will select the `nth` child. So if you specify 2, it'll do the second. If you want the 3rd, specify 3.

See their example, too.

```
$("ul li:nth-child(2)")
John
Karl - 2nd!
Brandon
```

I don't understand why you can't make it `j+2`.

Answer (score 0):

as jquery  documentation index for nth-child is not zero based.it starts from 1.